# Can't run nor debug project but gradle build+install work

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After update to Android studio 3.6 Canary11 (macOS) I cannot run nor run Debug variants of my project (Release variants working fine).

When I try to run the project I've got error:

```
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  > Entry name 'firebase-abt.properties' collided
```

But when I delete build directory (rm -rf app/build), I can run/debug project once time. After the first run, it is again with the same error with collision.

I try clear cache, restart the Android studio, but it didn't help.

Maybe it is not related to Android studio, because different project running ok. 
Do you have any idea, what the problem may be?

Answer (score 60):

I was facing the same error as [MrEngineer13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1167780/mrengineer13). After hours of struggle turns out you have to **delete the built APK files** for the project to build another APK successfully

Comment: Thank you so much. I struggled a lot with figuring out a similar issue  `Entry name org/joda/time/tz/data/Europe/Dublin collided` when generating an APK file. Deleting the previously generated APK (in its respective build folder) seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: I'm recently getting `Entry name 'org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/gen_approx_greeklatin.txt' collided` myself with the latest stable version of Android Studio (v4.0). Starting from v3.6.0 AS became a joke.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: what a hecking bug!

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue with Android Studio 3.6 Canary 12 on Mac, I could build different build variants but had this error when I tried to Generate a signed apk:

```
Entry name 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata' collided
```

I had to delete the .build folder as well as the folders where I build my build variant.

Comment: Where is the `.build` folder? I have a `build` folder without a `.`

Comment: Same worked for me. I delete build folder, under /app folder.

Comment: but its very entrupting and every time you run  alot of time the same issue do you what the specific reason is

Comment: I've added my answer here and It worked -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/61692128/7280036

Answer (score 8):

I faced somehow similar issue on  Android Studio 3.6.3v

```
Entry name 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata' collided
```

I resolved the issue by:

1. Delete `build` folder under `/app`
2. Clean project
3. Rebuild project

If still doesn't work, do the following:

```
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

Comment: Solved only with steps 2 and 3.
I would try those 2 steps first.
Thank you.

Comment: This is what I searched for.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar issue - my generating a debug build variant kept failing with an error about "Entry name res/layout/test_toolbar.xml collided". There is no "test_toolbar_xml" anywhere in my project. I first deleted all build directories and tried - same result. then I went in and deleted caches under .gradle\5.6.4, and under .idea folders. Tried again and this time I was able to build.

Building a "release" variant worked every time.

Answer (score 3):

Delete apk file from subfolders project

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the Android studio's new default packaging tool called **zipflinger**

You have to set the following in your **gradle.properties** file to fix the issue.

`android.useNewApkCreator=false`

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?authuser=1#zipflinger

Comment: Thanks a lot.I serch the questions several days.  Only this works for my case. Thanks a gain!

Answer (score 1):

try build.gradle

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
    pickFirst  'firebase-abt.properties'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still facing this issue, try this -

1. Step 1

```
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

2. Step 2

```
Rebuild Project
```

Comment: clean was enough for me to solve the problem thanx.

Answer (score 0):

1. After upgrading Gradle, compilation (debug) failed. I got the compilation error message:

`Entry name 'res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png' collided`

2. Tried the article https://medium.com/@elye.project/resources-collision-without-warning-b29294f518c6 by Elye.
   I am using a library where ic_launcher is also defined. I renamed the ic_launcher according to recommendations in the article, but that did not solve the problem.
3. Tried to clear the cache by deleting the build and gradle directory, but that did not solve the problem.
4. Tried to set in gradle.properties:`android.useNewApkCreator=false` but then Android Studio reports:
   build.gradle: The option setting `android.useNewApkCreator=false` is experimental and unsupported.
5. Since I am not up to using experimental features, I downgraded from:
   `Gradle Version: 3.6.1
   Android Plugin version: 6.2.1`
   to:
   `Gradle Version: 3.5.3
   Android Plugin version: 5.4.1`

Compilation (debug) now works again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I just clean and rebuild, and it's working fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

When getting a `entry name 'kotlin/collections/mapwithdefault.kotlin_metadata' collided` error in Android Studio v3.6.1 it helped cleaning the build folders.

We ended up creating a script for this: `cleanBuldFolders.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Deletes all build folders in the project
find . -name build -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when using **Android Studio 4.0 Canary 8**.

I solved my problem by downgrading from:

*Gradle version* `3.6.3` to `3.5.3`

*Android plugin version* `5.6.1` to `5.4.1`

**BUT**

I would suggest try these below options before downgrading

- Delete `build` folder inside `app`
- Clean
- Rebuild

If you still face the issue, try `Invalidate Cache / Restart`