# Android: Failed to build project with Android Studio 3.6

Tags: android

Can anyone help me fix this error? I got the error "Entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided" on Android Studio 3.6. However, I could not find anything wrong with the file. All activities are defined correctly. Below are the details of 'AndroidManifest.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.cmd.getcoin">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxx" />

        <activity android:name=".ui.activity.RewardAdsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.InstallAppActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.LuckyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <!-- Facebook Configuration -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_application_id"
            tools:replace="android:value" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            tools:replace="android:theme" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Krupa: No, I've not found a solution just yet

Comment: Yeap, that might be the best one. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run nor debug project but gradle build+install work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975595/cant-run-nor-debug-project-but-gradle-buildinstall-work)

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround, just try to downgrade your gradle version to 3.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your dependencies.
Some of them may use support instead of androidx.

I've fixed same problem in that way