# Getting error says - "Entry name 'res/layout/test_toolbar.xml' collided" while creating signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, signed-apk, build-variant

I have updated my android studio from **3.5.x** to **3.6** today and getting an error while generating signed apk for build variant showing the following message -  `Entry name 'res/layout/test_toolbar.xml'` collided
I don't have any layout named like this one in the whole project at all. I have a custom build variant named "**stage**" and whenever I am trying to build a signed apk, it always fails. I count find any solution yet. Please help me with this issue. Thanks

**Update:**
The same issue can occur with these following messages too (As I found it in **AS - 3.6.1** - **Continues with 4.x.x sometimes**). So don't worry about these kinds of unknown and not resolvable messages. So far I found two new types of messages while generating signed apk:

- `Entry name 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata' collided`
- `Access Denied`

The result is the same. Sometimes you may need to `Invalidate Cache and Restart` your AS for this.

Comment: Just delete that file, and rebuild.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

*Before reading the solution below, please read my update from 01.04.2020, the problem is deeper and it is in **your** code.*

**I've got the same problem after this 3.6 update.**

***The *fast* solution is:***

1. delete projectFolder\build
2. delete projectFolder\debug*
3. delete projectFolder\release*
4. delete projectFolder\app\build
5. delete projectFolder\app\build\debug*
6. delete projectFolder\app\build\release*

**So you need to delete all of the builds, debug and release directories.**

**Note that you may be not able to delete whole *debug and release* directories, but you can delete all of its contents.**

**UPDATE:**

I think they have fixed this bug today:
[image]

**UPDATE 03.03.2020:**
Unfortunately, the bug doesn't fix.

**UPDATE 01.04.2020:**
(Not 1st April joke:) )

Since month I worked with Android Studio developers and today I was told to use JDK instead of using JRE, because one of deep errors in logs said It.

After setting JDK (*File->Project Structure->SDK Location->JDK Location*) instead of JRE, I've got some other errors that were not shown in "build output" so I run *Analyze -> Inspect Code* and got **EIGHTEEN** errors such as referring to wrong view id in layouts, errors with orientation (hi to `tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource"`) and errors in manifest also with orientation: I read that this is some new update in 3.6.1 - about landscape or portrait `screenOrientation`, fixed fast by Studio with this:
`<activity tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />`

**When all of the errors were fixed with Analyze -> Inspect Code, I have successfully generated a signed APK using JDK and then using JRE (just for test).**

So in summary, this bug caused because of deep errors which you can find out only with `Inspect Code` tool.

I think AS will not think that this is a bug, I think they will say that this is a new feature for improving your code.
Also, I think you should try to inspect your code even without setting JDK instead of JRE.

**Additional recommendation from AS support:**

*BTW when exporting a `release` build, we also run `lintVital` which does some extra checks and has some errors marked as `fatal`. This check is expensive so it does not happen in `debug` builds*

Answer (score 72):

I deleted the previous build outputs for the build variant, including the APK file. That's what helped me

Comment: I tried deleting the `build` directory as a whole, still got the same issue. Can you elaborate what you did in full?

Comment: Are you delete build directory in root of the project and app/build directory too? In my project output path of apk is changed and I simply delete previous apk file where it was located.

Answer (score 54):

Problems encountered when upgrading to the latest Android Studio 3.6.1.
Clearing the cache, clean the project, and deleting the build folder did not solve the problem.

Just delete the apk generated by the previous compilation.

Answer (score 24):

While generating the apk, check for the destination folder, from which delete output.json and app-debug.apk from debug folder. Try building the same after this. 
AFAIK, it is a bug for android studio, hope they might fix this soon :)

Answer (score 23):

After updating to Android Studio 4.1 I faced similar issues, for me it was "entry name 'classes.dex' collided".
The error arose when building the app using the option 'Generate Signed Bundle/APK'.

The solution was simple: make sure Android Studio is not running the app when building (stop running and then try again).

Comment: Thanks for the tips ;-) For me, it was just that the phone was connected

Comment: This worked most of the time for me (AVD instead of phone connected) but sometimes needed an additional restart of Android Studio.

Answer (score 14):

This issue is resolved by deleting APKs generated by the previous builds existing in release and debug folders.

Invalidating cache and rebuild would not help if you have not deleted previously generated APKs

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error after updating Android Studio.

I fixed the problem by only cleaning the project (Build > Clean Project)

Answer (score 6):

I just delete all debug **APKs** in `myProject\app\build\outputs\apk\debug` directory and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes... Just delete the previous apk files and bob's your uncle ;  )

Answer (score 5):

This may have been overkill but I:

1. Delete project/build folder
2. Delete project/app/build folder
3. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
4. Clean Project

Answer (score 3):

It happen when you used auto viewBinding, Binding using Kotlin, or viewBinding feature of 3.6.

In case, you are adding files whose elements share the same IDs, ViewBinding confuses and creates such an error.

Let me help you by example
Adapter class which has two layout file separating by view Type :

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.frag_subscription_recommend.view.*


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
   return ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            if (viewType == 1) {
                R.layout.frag_subscription_recommend
            } else
                R.layout.frag_subscription_common,
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

onBinding(){
  holder.itemView.id_button_submit.setOnClickListener {}
}


 // which in case confusing which resource or layout full fill the requirement bcoz both have same ids of button.
```

in case you have to use :

```
 onBinding(){
  holder.itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.id_button_submit).setOnClickListener {}
}
```

which enables the old implementation.

Let me know if this working on your side?

Comment: Sorry, but the problem was with the build, debug and release directories. including output json file. Anyways, thhanks for your reply

Answer (score 3):

It's due to updated configuration changes in the Gradle.

So just try `File -> File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Answer (score 1):

Delete "ProjectFolder/build" folder of your project.
Make sure you Have Closed Android Studio, otherwise you would unable to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

To do a clean via the CLI, run `./gradlew clean` on the `/android` directory

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
Build 
  |-----> Clean project 
  |-----> Rebuild project
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had `entry name 'classes.dex' collided`

I just unplugged at the computer all four of the devices that I have been testing on.

Then the build succeeded.

Comment: I simply rebuilt a project and `Entry name 'classes.dex' collided` disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had [the same issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193437412). At issue' comments, I got the link to [another issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148641149#comment17), then I got a solution, which works for me.

Our project has the following lines at build.gradle(:app) specially for TeamCity

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "../../" + outputFileName
    }
}
```

But it crashes the local build process. 

**So I just add condition and fix the issue!**

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        if (rootProject.hasProperty("teamcity"))
            outputFileName = "../../" + outputFileName
    }
}
```

Comment: How this fix is working? Which string is to be used as property here?

Comment: The fix help me to build project on TeamCity, but local build stops with error. I add the condition and apply fix only if build process is running on TeamCity.