# Entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided (Build failed after updating the android gradle plugin to 3.6.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have recently updated the Android Studio from 3.5(stable) to 3.6(stable).

Then I saw the plugin update was also available, so I have updated the version of "com.android.tools.build:gradle" from 3.5.0 to 3.6.0 and also updated the gradle version to 5.6.4.

Now the problem starts when I try to build the project; it fails with message **Entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided**

[image]

Comment: can you add an error image for better understanding?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided
        at com.android.zipflinger.ZipArchive.validateName(ZipArchive.java:302)
        at com.android.zipflinger.ZipArchive.writeSource(ZipArchive.java:246)
        at com.android.zipflinger.ZipArchive.add(ZipArchive.java:126)
        at com.android.signflinger.SignedApk.add(SignedApk.java:135)
  ...
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        ... 3 more

Comment: I got the same issue. I run "./gradlew assembleDebug --debug" and got this 
error log "Task :app:packageDebug FAILED". It could be something wrong with the new packaging tool. Build successful after disabled it by adding "android.useNewApkCreator=false" in gradle.properties file

Comment: same here.. after updating android studio to 3.6 and updating all available plugin then this problem show up when try to Run app and Rebuild Project. **Entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided** don't know what to do.

Comment: Please have a look to similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60469132/10646780

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is caused by Android Gradle plugin 3.6

Revert to using the old packaging tool by including the following in your `gradle.properties` file will fix this issue

```
android.useNewApkCreator=false
```

More info please check the release note:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#zipflinger

Comment: where should you add this exactly?

Comment: gradle.properties

Comment: This is a useful answer. It could be even better if there was an explanation of what the new tool isn't liking.

Comment: I was going all ninja on this issue by cleaning my project. Invalidate and Restart for a million times. Thank this helped Also, my error was: Entry name 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata' collided

Comment: Using this, i get the error on installing that the APK cannot be parsed on the device.

Comment: This indeed worked. But why this property should be applied to my laptop but for others project is working fine even without this property?

Comment: I just got this error for bugsnag: `Entry name 'assets/include/bugsnag.h' collided` only when generating an APK from the `Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK` option. Adding this to gradle.properties fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: not sure why but `useNewApkCreator` this seems to cause the IDE to build the wrong variant! Still investigating but it seems to always build the last variant that I used for `Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK` even though I'm pressing the 'play' button after changing variants and cleaning!

Answer (score 21):

I found a workaround by adding this to the app's build.gradle:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

I had this to fix an issue with creating a bundle, due to Facebook's Audience Network, on Android Studio 3.5.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150373121) this happens when a JAR dependency contains an `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

For my project, the cause was this old dependency:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.android:android-test:4.1.1.4'
```

Which had a dependency on `com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4` which had an `AndroidManifest.xml` in the JAR.

**How I found it**

I searched in `$HOME\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1` for all `.jar` files containing an `AndroidManifest.xml` (I used Total Commander)

Then I cross referenced the results with the dependencies of my app. 
To get the dependency tree use the Gradle tool window to run the Tasks/android/androidDependencies gradle task.

Comment: Good idea. For me it was FirebaseCrashlytics

Comment: To use such 'com.google.android` libs correctly you should use `compileOnly` instead like `androidTestCompileOnly 'com.google.android:android-test:4.1.1.4'`

Answer (score 5):

I get a similar error: Entry name 'resources.arsc' collided. Workaround as @Marco Batista said:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'resources.arsc'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are few methods to resolve this issue.

1. Revert build.gradle version to 3.5.3

   ```
   dependencies {
          // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'       
             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
           }
   ```
2. Add packagingOptions under app/build.gradle

   ```
   android {
      ...

     packagingOptions {
         exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
     }

    }
   ```
3. Under gradle.properties, set **useNewApkCreator** to **false**. Adding this flag might cause some apk installation issues.

   ```
   android.useNewApkCreator=false
   ```

Final approach, perform a scan through third-party library. Check for **androidx.core:core-ktx** plugin. Try to update to 1.2.0 or newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with `AndroidManifest.xml` files colliding. First, I tried the `useNewApkCreator` workaround and it worked on the app variant I was working on. But when I switched to another variant, build was still successful but the app refused to install from Android Studio. Also installing the .apk manually gave parsing error on the device.

Finally, I analyzed the .apks from both variants and noticed that the broken .apk had the wrong AndroidManifest.xml in it. Excluding the manifest in `packagingOptions` worked though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with

```
android.useNewApkCreator=false
```

It was a quick win because I was able to compile, however the AndroidManifest.xml was still wrong. I found out because I needed to apply a hardening process to the APK and the tool was complaining about the AndroidManifest.xml.

This was because, as explained by others, the APK does not have its manifest but one from a dependency.
I discovered that by analysing the APK with Android Studio (build/analize APK), that pointed me right to the dependency with the problem.
The solution from Marco Batista was useful, but I put that in the dependency's gradle instead of in the app's one.

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    } 
}
```