# Unit testing: Entry name 'res/layout/test_toolbar.xml' collided

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-debug, test-coverage

I've tried to do some unit test example that included in an Android Studio project like `ExampleInstrumentedTest` and `ExampleUnitTest`, so the result is :

> Entry name 'res/layout/test_toolbar.xml' collided

I've searched everywhere on google but there's not answers to this specific problem, so any help will be grateful

here's the source of the basic unit test example :

**ExampleUnitTest**

```
 * Example local unit test, which will execute on the development machine (host).
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }}
```

[image]

**ExampleInstrumentedTest**

```
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();

        assertEquals("com.example.abder.emarque", appContext.getPackageName());
    }}
```

[image]

Comment: See similar error and possible solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68501093/1633493

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following  and It solved my problem.

1. Invalidate caches and Restart (File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart)
2. Clean Project (Build -> Clean Project)

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to same xml may be included in third party SDKs.
Solution: exclude 'res/layout/test_toolbar.xml' in packagingOptions of app's build.gradle file.

`packagingOptions { exclude 'res/layout/test_toolbar.xml' }`