# Problem "Entry name 'META-INF...' collide - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, apk, meta-inf

I have added some things to my mobile application, such as adds or animation-lists.
The thing is that I could generate APKs perfectly some days ago and, since the moment y added those things, Android Studio does not let me generate them. It has the following error.

> Entry name 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version' collided

Or these other ones:

> Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   Entry name 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version' collided

I have no idea what could get wrong.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 0.4 Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt) Try to use `exclude "META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable**"`

Answer (score 56):

I had the similar problem with "META-INF/androidx.gridlayout_gridlayout.version' collided".
It took my 4 hours and finally i resolved it.
Method which worked for me i am not sure that will for you too but you can try.
go to Menu  Build > Rebuild Project thats it.

Comment: Clear the build using Menu -> Build -> Clean project, and it worked.

Comment: For some weird reason I had to 'Clean Project' twice before it worked.

Comment: Menu -> Build -> Clean project,  worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Though I feel this will work in most situation, this did not really solve mine. @tmt 's answer worked: remove/rename the already-generated apk (and json).

Comment: `Build > Rebuild Project` helped me with `Entry name 'META-INF/androidx.preference_preference.version' collided` error.

Comment: Also you can try use something like that at your build.gradle(:app) : 
```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
 variant.outputs.all {
  outputFileName = "../../(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ")" + outputFileName
 }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

In my case in the output directory there has already been a file called app-debug.apk and for whatever reason the android sdk could not overwrite it. The apk has been generated as soon as I deleted or renamed the old version.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!! this solved my problem too.

Comment: this should be marked as the answer, brilliant, thank you!

Comment: See similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406047) and [possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68501093/1633493)

Answer (score 7):

Delete the previous APK you build and try again. it helps me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

- Click on Build -> Clean Project
- Click on File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Still you have the same error then delete debug and release folder from the app folder then restart the IDE

Answer (score 5):

Use in the below steps will working perfectly.

**Menu -> Build -> Clean project**

that's all. Enjoy your coding.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my project Clean Project, as well as Rebuild Project, which worked for me.

[image: Check this for more]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just rebuild the project. solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

In my case , I deleted the debug and release directory

Answer (score 0):

Solution **Clean Project** works, but it is not useful do clean every time before **Run**. 
So I created the [the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193437412). And at issue' comments I got link to [another issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148641149#comment17), then I got solution, which works for me.

My project has the following lines at build.gradle(:app) specially for TeamCity

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "../../" + outputFileName
    }
}
```

But it crash local build process. 

**So I just add condition and fix the issue!**

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        if (rootProject.hasProperty("teamcity"))
            outputFileName = "../../" + outputFileName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes cleaning and rebuilding the project is enough to resolve the issue but if not you can delete a previously generated debug apk from a project folder. generally, it happens when you create a building project first time after switching the branch or getting the latest changes from git, or changing the build variant.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).