# Entry name 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' collided when building for API 21 emulator, AS 4.0.1

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-4.0

When building for API 21 emulator in Android Studio 4.0.1 I get the error: "Entry name 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' collided". Building for other platform versions, emulator or device does work. Any ideas what might be wrong? My guess is there is a collision related to backward compatibility dependencies that Android build process injects for API 21, the error message does not help to isolate the problem. Running the build task itself t get more log output yields no problems ("Task execution finished 'build'.")

Comment: I faced the same issue. The problem was solved after I updated most of the libraries to the latest versions

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @straya?

Comment: I've continued to have problems with old emulators like this in recent years, sorry. I don't think I ever saw a fix for that case.

Comment: See similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406047) and [possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68501093/1633493)

Answer (score 0):

I had [the same issue][1]. At issue' comments I got link to [another issue][2], then I got solution, which works for me.

My project has the following lines at build.gradle(:app) specially for TeamCity

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "../../" + outputFileName
    }
}
```

But it crash local build process. 

**So I just add condition and fix the issue!**

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        if (rootProject.hasProperty("teamcity"))
            outputFileName = "../../" + outputFileName
    }
}
```

**Main point:** The *outputFileName* API doesn't officially support changing the *output file path*. A workaround would be to leave the *outputFileName* unchanged and instead add some post processing to copy to the desired location.