# entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run the project getting bellow error.

```
entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided
```

Comment: See similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406047) and [possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68501093/1633493)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line in gradle.properties will fix this issue

```
android.useNewApkCreator=false
```

Comment: As for me. My build.gradle(app) file has lines to change the outputFileName path. So I use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68501093/1633493) and fix my problem