# Entry name 'play-services-ads-identifier.properties' collided

Tags: google-play-services

Facing a build error while running the app, Previously Signed APKs Builds worked correctly,But after that while running the app simply on device with(Run 'app') this error occured in Android studio

Entry name 'play-services-ads-identifier.properties' collided

Comment: I fixed this by deleting the previous signed APK's from debug and release directory and then 'clean' project and 'Invalidate caches/restart'.

Comment: See similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406047) and [possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68501093/1633493)