# Entry name 'org/joda/time/tz/data/Europe/Dublin' collided

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build, jodatime

I got this error suddenly when compiled a signed Apk, and not sure how to fix it.

```
Entry name 'org/joda/time/tz/data/Europe/Dublin' collided
```

It's not pointing to any line, this is the Joda library import:

```
implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9"
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the if you're enabling proguard while building this, or minifying it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the same error on the latest JodaTime version - 2.10.5. But only with some flavors. It seems as a gradle build error.
In the my case - I have deleted ./app/build/ folder and then start "Invalidate cache and restart".

Comment: yes, it seems like a gradle build error. it keeps happen randomly to me, from time to time.

Comment: Same with JodaTime version 2.10.6. Deleting the build folder contents and "Invalidate Cache and restart" solved it

Comment: Anyone been able to get to the root of the actual issue?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is trying to generate an APK (and your APK output folder is outside of the build folder), but still having issues after deleting the build folder, and doing "Invalidate cache and restart" on Android Studio, try deleting the previously generated .apk file from your respective APK output folder. See first answer in related question [Can't run nor debug project but gradle build+install work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975595/cant-run-nor-debug-project-but-gradle-buildinstall-work)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but only on one build variant, I made sure all my `gradle` files were up-to date but that didn't fixed it.

To solve it I closed `android studio` and navigated to the `project file` click on the app folder and deleted the build folder.

Once deleted I reopened Android Studio and launched the android project,

I then clicked `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`.

This worked for me and can now run every build variant without any problems, I've not had the same issue since.

Answer (score -1):

After try everything on all forums, I just opened the route for the file on Notepad++, after on my project, tried the Signed bundle and the Signed APK... both works excellent now haha.
Hope this works for you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssnfB.png)