# I m facing some ERROR in Android Manifest xml how can I solve these error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, build-error

I m facing some issues during building the app in android studio.. in ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML file

***ERRORS***

*Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig'.

> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
> Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
> > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Utkarsh/Desktop/solidvpn-100/SolidVPNsource%20code/SolidVPN/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 28; columnNumber: 9; The value of attribute "android:value" associated with an element type "meta-data" must not contain the '<' character.*

code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.maskmyip.vpnsain">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <application
        android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.activity.Application"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-7361016462220350~1455148367 />


        <activity android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.activity.ConnectionEditorActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.activity.FragActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.activity.TokenImportActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="127.0.0.1"
                    android:path="/securid/ctf"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="rsa.com"
                    android:path="/android/token/ctf"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="com.rsa.securid" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="com.rsa.securid.iphone" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.sdtid"
                    android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.handlers.FileSelect"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.activity.MainActivity"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            tools:ignore="ExportedActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




        <activity
            android:name="org.acra.CrashReportDialog"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

        <service
            android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.core.OpenVpnService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="app.openconnect.api.GrantPermissionsActivity"
            android:permission="app.openconnect.REMOTE_API">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="app.openconnect.api.ConfirmDialog"
            android:permission="app.openconnect.REMOTE_API">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.handlers.OnBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.handlers.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.FileProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedmodule"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposeddescription"
            android:value="Bypass Android VPN confirmation dialog" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedminversion"
            android:value="30" />


        <service android:name="com.maskmyip.vpnsain.notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_luncher" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Error is very clear you are missing closed tags in your line no. 28                                   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-7361016462220350~1455148367" />  for android:value you are not closing the double quotes

Comment: that issue has been solved but new issue arrises                                                                                Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > Entry name 'assets/VERSION' collided

Comment: clean and rebuid project again

Comment: no improvement     same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the missing `"` for the `meta-data` tag:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-7361016462220350~1455148367" />
```

And for the `Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable > Entry name 'assets/VERSION' collided` error I've already provided a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60417285/4399414), hope it helps.